# how to execute query with constant in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

while executing query got this error "Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax"

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql  = "SET @a:=0;UPDATE registrations SET EXIBIT_NO=@a:=@a+1 ORDER BY GR_ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrtie:

`$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`

**Code Example:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: i dont want select but require sequential nos according to order by gr_id. if only update query fired it executed correctly but for constant @a it give error